# Loseless monochrome video codec

Tags: video-streaming, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to create an application that will stream a monochrome video over the network. Each pixel of frame carries important information (it is something like a mask) so the pixels can not change their values on the output. What is the best (and not too hard) way to stream a monochrome video without losing any data (using lossless compression/codec)? I'm using the Media Foundation library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to need a lossless encoder and a method to transfer frames over network. Media Foundation API is close but does not have this option available with stock software.

Perhaps the easiest way would be to extract video frames from video pipeline at the most convenient point, process it with a lossless still image codec (popular PNG will do fine) and transfer over network using a non Media Foundation API method.

Staying within Media Foundation, you will have to integrate a codec and a media sink, which might be a more elegant solution, from a certain standpoint, however I don't think it qualifies as "not too hard" requested above.